# 3 condition in WHERE clause for filtering

Tags: c#, filter

Basically I am trying to filter the distinct time and temperature from my database based on 3 condition.

1. (column) UnitNo = txtUnit.Text (what user input in textbox)
2. (Start date) Date >=ComboStart.Text (what user selected for 1st combobox)
3. (End date) Date <=ComboEnd.Text (what user selected for 2nd combobox)

I know the WHERE clause is wrong.. could someone please help?

Thanks in advance

```
string tableName = "Data3";
string query = "SELECT DISTINCT Time,Temperature FROM Data3 WHERE (UnitNo = txtUnit.Text) AND (Date >= ComboStart.Text) AND (Date<=ComboEnd.Text)";


OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\acer\Documents\Database3.accdb");
OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);

DataSet set = new DataSet(); 
ada.Fill(set, tableName);  

DataTable tab = new DataTable();
tab = set.Tables["Data3"];  

dataGridViewDisplay.DataSource = tab;
```

Comment: what is the problem with where? filtering means using where!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with wrong on your where-clause? Do you get any errors? What results do you get and what do you expect instead?

Comment: @dotctor there is no prob with WHERE clause i mean idk if the way i phase my WHERE clause is right or wrong..

Comment: @HimBromBeere it dont seems to filter anything. I'm suppose to get the particular UnitNo's info between the date I have selected.

Comment: Access (I'm guessing from the provider) cannot see/read from the textboxes in your application.

Comment: @HansKesting textbox input is doing fine.. I had problem trying to filter through the selection in combo box instead

Comment: @Athena - Yes, at this point in your code, `txtUnit.Text` contains the correct value. However, when you put "txtUnit.Text" in that command string, it is literally that and *not* the contained value. Access then sees "txtUnit.Text" and doesn't know how to handle that and either gives an error orit is "no match" (so no results).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use parameterized query like

```
string query = 
  @"SELECT DISTINCT Time, Temperature 
    FROM Data3 
    WHERE (UnitNo = ?)
    AND   (Date >= ?)
    AND   (Date <= ?)";
```

And then add parameters like:

```
ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Unit", txtUnit.Text));
ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("DateFrom", ComboStart.Text));
ada.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("DateTo", ComboEnd.Text));
```

Comment: but i had this error.. "The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects."

Comment: You have to make a `OleDbParameter` type object, because `ComboStart.Text`, `ComboEnd.Text` and `txtUnit.Text` are strings.

Comment: @Athena oh, I missed correct syntax. `Parameters.Add` expects `OleDbParameter`, so see update.

Comment: thanks guy for the advice! it's working perfectly now.. I learnt sth new again. Great help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string query = "SELECT  DISTINCT " +
                           "         Time," +
                           "         Temperature " +
                           " FROM    Data3 " +
                           " WHERE  (UnitNo = " + txtUnit.Text + ")"+
                           " AND    (Date >= '" + ComboStart.Text +"')" +
                           " AND    (Date <= '" + ComboEnd.Text + "')";
```

You need to concatenate values from controls into that query.
This will solve your error, but it's not considered as best practice to use SQL like this. Please consider parameterized query like Andy suggested.

Comment: Terrible suggestion. Have you ever heard about sql injection?

Comment: An ever better solution would be to use parameters to prevent injection attacks. What if txtUnit.Text contained `1 OR 1=1 --`?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev, access is being used, I suppose it's a homework question.

Comment: No matter, is it homework or not - I can't find the reason to teach someone for something that is considered as bad practice.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but OP also needs to know why that piece of code didn't work that was written by him/her right? that is also learning.